# How can I post an equation in textbook form?

Tags: support

I am trying to describe a differential equation I am putting into `NDSolveValue`. However, it is complicated and I would like to express it in textbook form before I show how I have put it into Mathematica form. I have tried copying from traditional form but this does not work. Any suggestions?

Trying the suggestion I wish to copy the Laplacian so the Mathematica form is

```
Laplacian[\[Phi][x, y, t], {x, y}]
```

then using TexForm

```
TeXForm[Laplacian[\[Phi][x, y, t], {x, y}]]
```

which gives

\phi ^{(0,2,0)}(x,y,t)+\phi ^{(2,0,0)}(x,y,t)

You then have to put a $ before and after as a delimiter.

$\phi ^{(0,2,0)}(x,y,t)+\phi ^{(2,0,0)}(x,y,t)$

This is not converting to textbook form here but it works fine on the main site. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Use `TeXForm[]` and copy it into the site, which supports MathJax. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: @J.M.  I still don't understand I have edited my post to try your suggestion.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: As noted in the help page I linked to, delimit your TeX with `$` for inline display and `$$` for centered display. Also, MathJax is apparently not enabled on meta, unlike in math.SE.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I tried it out, as you say, you have to put the delimiter before and after. All works nicely now.

Answer (score 4):

You may also highlight the output formula and select to *Copy As | LaTeX*.

[image]

This will paste as LaTeX.

> \phi ^{(0,2,0)}(x,y,t)+\phi ^{(2,0,0)}(x,y,t)

This has the benefit of not needing to type in `TeXForm`. It also works on other formatted output like `Grid`.

```
Grid@Table[i - x^j, {i, 2}, {j, 2}]
```

> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1-x & 1-x^2 \
> 2-x & 2-x^2 \
> \end{array}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks something else to experiment with.